# Why the reference to an object in java is not modified when re-assigning the object?

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-value, mutated

I have this piece of code, and I would like to know why the reference of my variable x is not modified ? It still points to the first object assigned:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Object x = new Object();
    Object y = x;
    mutate(x);
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(x.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(y.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(x == x); // true
    System.out.println(x == y); // true
 }

 public static void mutate(Object x) {
     x = new String();
 }
```

}

Comment: Because Java is pass by value. The other important part here: please do prior research the next time. This is basic, elemental stuff; documented a zillion times out there; and probably asked and answered here even more often.

Comment: Because Java is pass-by-value (and references are passed by value); see the question of which this is considered a duplicate for a detailed explanation.

Comment: So what is the difference with adding a final modifier to the method ?